# CSS link attributes in classes .net

Tags: asp.net

How can you specify link attributes inside a class in main.css.

The standard link attribute is fine when put in a non defined area of the CSS file.

```
a:link { color:white }
```

However if I want to create a class so that I am only defining how the attributes apply to a menu it errors as a syntax error. For example.

```
menuLinks {
           a:link { color:white }
}
```

Will show as an error, so how can I define link attributes within a class. I am using visual web developer 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "nest" brace blocks.

Assuming `menuLinks` is the `id` of the object, use this...

```
#menuLinks a:link { color:white; }
```

If `menuLinks` is the `class` of the object, use this...

```
.menuLinks a:link { color:white; }
```

**UPDATE** based on comments...

Instead of having the individual blocks like this...

```
#Menu a:link { color:white; }
#Menu a:link { text-decoration:none; }
```

You can combine them into a single block...

```
#Menu a:link { color:white; text-decoration:none; }
```

Which can also be written like this which can be easier to read, depending on how many items you have...

```
#Menu a:link {
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: So if I have defined a <div>menuLinks</div> in my masterpage and the menu contains the links I want to adjust I can use the .menuLinks notation within the css defition  #menuLinks { .menuLinks a:link { color:white; }
.menuLinks a:hover { color:blue; }
}

Comment: @sayth, I think you need to learn about about HTML and CSS. I stated in the answer that the brace blocks (i.e. `{ }`) **cannot** be nested.

Comment: @sayth, have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html) which will give you an idea of how to format CSS and how the `id` and `class` definitions are handled

Comment: Thank you for the help. This solved it for me.                       #Menu a:link { color:white; }
#Menu a:link { text-decoration:none; }
#Menu a:visited { color:White; }

Comment: Nice one @sayth, well done :-)  However, let me show you a slightly better way of doing it, I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a [descendent selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors)

```
menuLinks a:link {}
```

Note that:

- `menuLinks` will match `<menuLinks>` which is not valid HTML
- CSS doesn't have classes (and is not an object oriented programming language). It has rules, which are contained in rule-sets, which are prefixed with a selector. (CSS does have a class selector which selects HTML (or other markup language) classes)
- CSS doesn't have attributes, it has values, properties, rules, rule-sets, and a few other things.